# Working with dates

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I subtract two dates from each other because I need the time difference between them.  I toggle the usual problems but when I write it to MySQL (Time) I see there is always 1 hour too much difference.  If I expect 2 min difference I get 1 h 2 min.  Now I think it's a timezone problem but is there a way to solve this ... ?

```
Date totalDate = visit.getTotalTime(); 
Date visitDate = visit.getVisitTime(); 
java.sql.Time sqlTotalTime = new java.sql.Time(totalDate.getTime() - visitDate.getTime()); 
ps.setTime(4, sqlTotalTime);
```

gives 1h 2 sec difference and not 2 sec:

```
08/Dec/2010:07:27:54 
08/Dec/2010:07:27:52
```

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps relevant code snippet will help someone give ideas

Comment: I have no idea what "I toggle the usual problems " means?

Comment: "Toggle the usual problems"? Much more detail definitely required.

Comment: Date totalDate = visit.getTotalTime(); Date visitDate = visit.getVisitTime(); java.sql.Time sqlTotalTime = new java.sql.Time(totalDate.getTime() - visitDate.getTime()); ps.setTime(4, sqlTotalTime);                                                       08/Dec/2010:07:27:54      08/Dec/2010:07:27:52   gives 1h 2 sec difference and  not 2 sec

Comment: @Darth Blue Ray: please edit your post and paste the above comment as a code block in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not explaining how exactly you are subtracting the two dates or what "the usual problems" are according to you.

To get the time difference between two dates, you can call `getTime()` on both of them to get the number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 GMT and then subtract these two values:

```
long differenceInMilliseconds = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
```

Ofcourse, if you want the difference in seconds, minutes, hours etc. then divide this value by the appropriate factor.

Note that a `java.util.Date` object does by itself not hold any information about time zones.

*edit* (after your edit) It looks like you are trying to store the time difference in a column of type TIMESTAMP or something similar. Don't do that; TIMESTAMP etc. are meant for time values, not time *difference* values. Just store the time difference in a numeric column.

Comment: I edited my post ... so I need to add information about my time Zone I use?

Comment: true ... problem is, I'm stuck with the TIME in MySql ... I'm kind of "forced" to use it ....

Comment: @Darth Blue Ray - then I think you have to "unforce" it by pointing out that the database schema is unworkable to whoever designed it.